# drive.readonly.metadata not enough for revisions.list

Tags: google-drive-api

I've been using the [Google APIs Client Library for JS](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/) heavily to access the revision history of some files and see if they are published on the web, for the last 2 weeks and using the drive.readonly.metadata scope.

The following code worked until this morning

```
function checkRevision(childItem, language) {
    var requestRevision = gapi.client.drive.revisions.list({
        'fileId': childItem.id,
        'fields': 'items/publishedOutsideDomain'
    });

    var fileId = childItem.id;
    requestRevision.execute(function(revisions) {

        //Check if the latest revision is published
        if (revisions && !revisions.error) {
            if (revisions.items[revisions.items.length - 1].publishedOutsideDomain) {
                addBlogPostToMenu(fileId, language);//the file is ok do the real job
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Not the response I get from `requestRevision.execute` is

```
403 Forbidden

    {
     "error": {
      "errors": [
       {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden",
        "message": "Forbidden"
       }
      ],
      "code": 403,
      "message": "Forbidden"
     }
    }
```

The webapp was authorized correctly with

```
    gapi.auth.authorize({
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly.metadata',
        'immediate': true
    },
    handleAuthResult);
```

Changing the scope to `drive.readonly` fixed it but I think revisions are metadata and not the actual file so `drive.readonly.metadata` should be the most appropriate scope.

P.S. even tried with the [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/list) and I get the same error.

Sample File Id :

> 1ppLjLg2_ItTGHn_tVSEyOm2bwOtfqiGEb4MZQyAnE7c

Comment: If your app suddenly stopped working yesterday, it might be linked with this https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/issues/detail?id=103 . There is no obvious connection, but it does all depend on how your JS handles the exception described in the bug report.

I would agree with you that drive.readonly.metadata should be sufficient scope to process revision feeds, but it would be great to see that documented somewhere.

Comment: @pinoyyid. Nope it's not related to auth request. Even from the api explorer the error is the same and simply changing the scope fix it. P.S. the error was extracted by debugging the js code in chrome and the auth was made with immediate= true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior, similarly files.list don't respond back with `exportLinks` or a `downloadUrl` if you're only authorized for `drive.readonly.metadata`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; so, to wrap it up, now it's working as expected and before, when it worked with `drive.readonly.metadata`, was wrong.